# Cannot change Business Unit

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working with CRM 2011. I created a new organization ORG with a Service Account SRVACC. I created 2 other users with system admin role. I also created One Business Unit. So now in my System I have one Parent Business & one Child Business unit, 2 System admin users and One SRVACC with system admin role.

For testing purpose, i changed the BU of the SRVACC from parent BU to child BU. The problem is that now I cannot change it back to the parent BU for the SRVACC record.

Can someone please help.

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #9D70E497Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #9D70E497</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-10-06T07:23:41.398256Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220943</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Principal user (Id=f55c3ae0-5748-e411-bb3d-005056a77686, type=8) is missing prvReadAsyncOperation privilege (Id=e84acc8f-0c61-43e3-a716-20964a483bdf)</Message>
    <Timestamp>2014-10-06T07:23:41.398256Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the Error you will find:

> Principal user (Id=f55c3ae0-5748-e411-bb3d-005056a77686, type=8) is
>   missing prvReadAsyncOperation privilege
>   (Id=e84acc8f-0c61-43e3-a716-20964a483bdf)

`prvReadAsyncOperation` privilege is the `Read` privilege for `System Job` Entity (Role `Customization` tab):

[image]

Comment: I am editing the Business Unit with System Admin Role. The Admin role always has the highest set of privileges.

Comment: Why exactly is this privilege needed anyways? Is it just the case that arbitrary changes might trigger a 'system job' and thus Dynamics requires users trying to make those changes be able to 'read' those jobs? Do you have links to any info about any this you could share?

Comment: @KennyEvitt I don't know why this specific privilege is required for the BU change operation